# Resharper: formatting if statements?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, resharper

I've been using ReSharper a lot recently, and I must say I am enjoying it, although I couldn't find the setting for a certain something.

Take the below code for example, I have these chunks of if statements, infact I think ReSharper might force it to be formatted like this but they're all pushed together.

```
if (something) 
{ 
    // potentially do something
}
if (somethingElse)
{
    // potentially do something else 
}
if (somethingElseAgain)
{
    // potentially do something else again
}
```

In a usual project, without resharper it would probably be set out better, somethin like the layout shown below maybe?

```
if (something) 
{ 
    // potentially do something
}

if (somethingElse)
{
    // potentially do something else 
}

if (somethingElseAgain)
{
    // potentially do something else again
}
```

See how much nicer it looks? Now, getting to the actual question, I couldn't find any option to add line breaks after an if statement, only before it? and even if I applied that, it still wouldn't fix the issue I currently have?

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this issue so that when I run code cleanup it actually fixes this?

Answer (score 1):

I checked your example but do not get the same result.
What's your if-statement configuration? Here is a screenshot of mine to compare it with yours:

[image]

To access this menu highlighted the if-statements, a brush appears on the right, right click that brush, and select Format selection -> Configure... from the sub-menu.

[image]

You may also want to check ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Braces Layout...

Comment: Hi, can I ask how you got that window open, it seems I have different settings when viewing it from the full settings menu in Resharper.